# If $a^3+a^2+a=9b^3+b^2+b$ and $a,b$ are integers then show $a-b$ is a perfect cube.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, perfect-powers

If $a^3+a^2+a=9b^3+b^2+b$ and $a,b$ are integers then show $a-b$ is a perfect cube.

**My attempt**:I factorized it like below:

$(a-b)(a^2+b^2+ab+a+b+1)=8b^3=(2b)^3$

I take $\gcd(a-b,a^2+b^2+ab+a+b+1)=d$

If $d=1$ then it is clear that $a-b$ is a perfect cube then consider $d>1$ then there is a $p$ that is prime and $p \mid d$.We have :

$p\mid a-b \Rightarrow p \mid (2b)^3 \Rightarrow p \mid 2b \Rightarrow p\mid 2$ or $p\mid b$

If $p\mid b$ then also $p\mid a$ (as $p\mid a-b$ holds). Then we will get to $p \mid 1$ because:

$ p \mid a^2+b^2+ab+a+b,p \mid a^2+b^2+ab+a+b+1 \Rightarrow p \mid 1$

which is clearly wrong then we have $p\mid 2$ so $p=2$ means $d=2^k$ where $k$ is a natural number including $0$.In the case $d=1$ we have the right result. So assemble $k \ge 1$.Because $2 \mid a-b$ we can conclude that $a,b$ have the same parity @Ghartal showed in his answer that if $a,b$ are both even we have a right result but if $a,b$ are both odd we don't. So maybe we have to prove $a,b$ can't be both odd.

Comment: Isn't $(2b)^3=8b^3$ always a perfect cube?

Comment: @kingW3 It was a type mistake we should prove $a-b$ is a perfect cube.

Comment: Note that $$\gcd(a-b,a^2+b^2+ab+a+b+1)=\gcd(a-b,3b^2+2b+1)=d$$and if a prime $p$ divides $d$, then it divides $2b$. But if $p$ divides $b$, then it is contradiction because it should divide $3b^2+2b+1$ too and $\gcd(b,3b^2+2b+1)=1$. Therefore $p=2$ and $d$ is power of $2$. But I cannot prove $a-b$ is perfect cube...

Comment: @didgogns I showed the same thing in my answer.

Comment: I don't understand how $p|a$ or $p|2$ from $p|2b$.

Comment: $a=b=0$ is only solution. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integer+solution+a%5E3%2Ba%5E2%2Ba%3D9b%5E3%2Bb%5E2%2Bb

Comment: @didgogns if a prime like p is such $p \mid ab$ then $p \mid a$ or $p\mid a$.For prove consider $p$ doesn't divide $a$ then $gcd(a,p)=1$ and then $p \mid b$

Comment: $p|2b$ -> $p|2$ or $p|b$ -> $p|a(a^2+a+1)$ -> $p|a$ or $p|a^2+a+1$. I don't see how you excluded the case $p|a^2+a+1$.

Comment: @didgogns $p \mid a-b$,$p \mid 2b \Rightarrow p \mid a+b \Rightarrow p \mid 2a$

Comment: Now I understand.

Comment: Why does $p|a, p|b$ imply $p|1$? Nowhere is stated that $a,b$ are relatively prime and it cannot be deduced from the given relation.

Comment: @sku's proof is correct, we can't exclude the case when $a-b=4m^3$, $b=mn$ and $a^2+b^2+a+b+1=2n^3$, where $m$, $n$ are odd integers such that $\gcd(m,n)=1$. This simplifies to $16m^6+12m^4n+4m^3+3m^2n^2+2mn+1=2n^3$.

Comment: @N.S. it comes from how he defined $p$, which divides $d$ which is $gcd(a-b,a^2+b^2+ab+a+b+1)=d$. If $p$ divides both $a$ and $b$ then you get $gcd(a-b,a^2+b^2+ab+a+b+1)=gcd(px,py+1)=1$ for some $x$ and $y$

Comment: It is quite elementary to show that $d=1$ or $d=2$, but I am not sure how to rule out the second case.

Comment: @Sil We have $p=2$ so $d=2^k$ which gives a more general case.

Comment: @TahaAkbari My point is that $k>1$ cannout occur, so only possible options are $k=0$ or $k=1$ (or in other words $d=1$ or $d=2$). This is because we know that $2$ cannot divide $b$ (it would then from $2 | a-b$ followed that $2|a$ and then $2 \nmid a^2+b^2+ab+a+b+1$, contradiction). But if $2$ does not divide $b$, and $2^k$ divides both of the terms in product, then it follows $2^k 2^k = 2^{2k} | 8$, which implies $k\leq 1$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It turns out that there are only two *rational* solutions of
$a^3+a^2+a = 9b^3+b^2+b$.  One is the obvious integer solution
$(a,b)=(0,0)$, for which $a-b$ is the cube $0$.
The other is $(a,b) = (-7/5, -3/5)$, for which $a-b = -4/5$
is not a cube but $a,b$ are not integers.  So $a-b$ is indeed
a cube for all the integer solutions, as desired.

The proof that there are no other rational solutions is elementary,
but requires Fermat's method of descent.  The equation
$a^3+a^2+a = 9b^3+b^2+b$ defines a smooth cubic curve with
a rational point at $(a,b)=(0,0)$, so it's an elliptic curve
that we can bring to standard form $y^2=\text{cubic}(x)$ by
projecting from the origin.

Let $(a,b)$ be any rational solution other than $(0,0)$.
Then $b\neq 0$ because the nonzero solutions of $a^3+a^2+a$
are not rational (or even real). Write $a=mb$ and divide by $b$ to get
$$
(9-m^3) b^2 + (1-m^2) b + (1-m) = 0.
$$
This equation is quadratic in $b$, so it has rational solutions **iff**
the discriminant is a square.  The discriminant is
$$
-3 m^4 + 4 m^3 - 2 m^2 + 36 m - 35 = (1-m)(3m-7)(m^2+2m+5).
$$
Taking $m=1$ yields $8b^2 = 0$, so we're back to the $b=0$ solution;
and $m=7/3$ yields $-4(5b+3)^2/27 = 0$, so $b=-3/5$ and $a=-7/5$.
We claim that there are no other solutions.

If $m\neq 1$ we may write $m = 1+(8/x)$ and calculate
$$
-3 m^4 + 4 m^3 - 2 m^2 + 36 m - 35 = \frac{2^8}{x^4} (x^3-2x^2-16x-48),
$$
so we seek rational points on the elliptic curve
$$
y^2 = x^3-2x^2-16x-48 = (x-6)(x^2+4x+8)
$$
other than the "point at infinity".
The point $(x,y)=(6,0)$ brings us back to $m = 1 + (8/6) = 7/3$,
and it turns out there are no others.  Since the cubic on the right-hand side 
has a linear factor, we can try to prove this using Fermat's descent,
which turns out to be enough.  But these days there are other
resources we can try first: Cremona's **mwrank** or the
[LMFDB](http://www.lmfdb.org), and either of these
tells us that there are no other solutions and that Fermat-style descent
suffices to prove it.  In the case of **mwrank** we'd need a bit of
additional computation to exclude other torsion points, so let's go the
database route: enter the coefficients **[0,-2,0,-16,-48]** into the
"curve, label or isogeny class label" search window for
[elliptic curves
over $\bf Q$](http://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/), and find the entry for
[this curve of
conductor 544](http://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/544/a/2) (which is small enough that it's also in Cremona's book).
We find that the curve has only the known two torsion points
and rank zero, and moreover that the 2-part of the Tate-Shafarevich group
is trivial, so a 2-descent suffices to establish rank zero.
This completes the proof.

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** This is not a complete solution. It may give others some clues.

We have that $$(a-b)(a^2+b^2+ab+a+b+1)=8b^3 \tag{1}$$ Let

$$d=\gcd(a-b, a^2+b^2+ab+a+b+1).$$

And let $p$ be an odd prime divisor of $d$. Then $p \mid a-b$ and $p \mid b$. It follows that $p|a$. Since $p \mid a^2+b^2+ab+a+b+1$ we get $p \mid 1$. Contradiction. Thus only prime divisor of $d$ is $2$.

From equation $(1)$ observe that $a$ and $b$ have the same parity. Thus $a-b$ is even. So let $a-b=c=2^k (2l+1)$, where $l$ is an integer. Equation $(1)$ becomes.

$$c(3b^2+c^2+3bc+2b+c+1)=8b^3 \tag{2}$$

Notice that if $b$ is an even number then $3b^2+c^2+3bc+2b+c+1$ will be odd. Hence

$$d=\gcd\big(c, 3b^2+c^2+3bc+2b+c+1\big)=1.$$ And $c$ is a perfect cube. Now, suppose that $b$ is odd. Then, since $3b^2+1 \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$ we get
$$3b^2+c^2+3bc+2b+c+1=3b^2+1+c(c+1+3b)+2b \\ =4m+2b=2(2m+b)$$Thus the highest power of $2$ dividing LHS of equation $(2)$ is $k+1$. And since $v_2($RHS$)=3$ we get that $k=2$. Thus $a-b=4(2l+1)$ cannot be a cube.

Maybe in this case there is no solution for the equation at all.

Comment: But $8l+4$ can be a cube of $8k+2$?

Comment: Let $4(2l+1)=j^3$. then $j$ is even and $$4(2l+1)=8j'^3$$ or $$2l+1=2j'^3,$$which is not possible. Thus $4(2l+1)$ cannot be a cube.

Comment: I think your answer is complete.What is it missing?

Comment: Well , the question says prove that $a-b$ is a perfect cube. But I have shown that in some cases It cannot be a cube! And actually we don't know yet that if there are some solutions in later case or not!

Comment: It gives us the idea to show that there are no solutions in that case +1.

Comment: Yasha for the upvote. Actually I doubt that there are solutions other than $a=b=0$. Where did you see this question?

Comment: As http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integer+solution+a%5E3%2Ba%5E2%2Ba%3D9b%5E3%2Bb%5E2%2Bb says it is the only solution.

Comment: Wolfram cannot provide all solutions! And it cannot prove that its the only solution!

Comment: I think it can provide all solutions.Can't it?

Comment: @TahaAkbari Where did you see this problem and are you sure that the result is correct?

Comment: @YuxiaoXie  I got it in an olympiad number theory book.

Comment: @TahaAkbari What's the title of the book?

Comment: @YuxiaoXie An intro to number theory(persian).

Answer (score 2):

If $a-b=0\Longrightarrow b=0$ and $a-b$ is a perfect cube.
Also $a=0\Longleftrightarrow b=0$ and $a-b$ is a perfect cube.

---

Assume $a-b\ne0~\wedge~a\ne0~\wedge~b\ne0$.

Let's factorize $a^3+a^2+a=9b^3+b^2+b$.
$\begin{array}{rrcl}
& (a^3-b^3)+(a^2-b^2)+(a-b) & = & 8b^3\\
\Longrightarrow & (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)+(a-b)(a+b)+(a-b) & = & 8b^3\\
\Longrightarrow & (a-b)(a^2+b^2+ab+a+b+1) & = & (2b)^3\\
\Longrightarrow & (a-b)\big(a^2+b^2+a(b+1)+(b+1)\big) & = & (2b)^3\\
\Longrightarrow & \underbrace{(a-b)}_X\underbrace{\big(a^2+b^2+(a+1)(b+1)\big)}_Y & = & (2b)^3
\end{array}$

Define $d=\gcd(X,Y)$.
Suppose $d>1\Longrightarrow\exists p\in\mathbb{N}:p\mid d$ and $p$ is prime.
Suppose $p>2\Longrightarrow p\mid X\Longrightarrow p\mid8b^3\Longrightarrow p\mid b^3\Longrightarrow p\mid b$.
Then $p\mid X~\wedge~p\mid b\Longrightarrow p\mid a\Longrightarrow p\mid a^2~\wedge~p\mid b^2$.
Then $p\mid Y~\wedge~p\mid(Y-1)\Longrightarrow p\mid1$.
***Contradiction*** because $p>1\Longrightarrow p=2~\vee~d=1$.

If $a$ and $b$ are either both even neither both odd, then $X$ is odd and $a^2+b^2$ is odd and $(a+1)(b+1)$ is even, then $Y$ is odd so $2\nmid d$, and that's a ***contradiction*** because $8\mid XY$.

So $a$ and $b$ have the same parity, then $2\mid X$.

Suppose both $a$ and $b$ are even, then $a^2+b^2$ is even and $(a+1)(b+1)$ is odd, then $Y$ is odd. So $\gcd(X,Y)=1$, then $a-b$ is a perfect cube (it's easy to prove it).

Suppose both $a$ and $b$ are odd, then $\gcd(X,Y)=2$.
Also $\gcd(X,b)=1$, since $X\mid8b^3\Longrightarrow X\mid8\Longrightarrow8\le|X|\le8$.
But $|X|\ne8$ otherwise $Y\mid b^3$ but $2\mid Y\Longrightarrow2\mid b$.
***Contradiction*** because $2\nmid b\Longrightarrow|X|=2~\wedge~|X|=4$.

***Note:*** From now, the exercise contains a lot of work of pick & spade.

Since $\gcd(X,b)=\gcd(a-b,b)=1\Longrightarrow\gcd(a,b)=1$ (It's easy to prove it).
We have $a^3+a^2+a=9b^3+b^2+b\Longrightarrow a(\underbrace{a^2+a+1}_A)=b(\underbrace{9b^2+b+1}_B)$
Then $a\mid B~\wedge~b\mid A$.
Let's define $f(x)=x^3+x^2+x$ and $g(x)=9x^3+x^2+x$, so we need $f(a)=g(b)$.

- ***First case:*** $a-b=2\Longrightarrow a=b+2~\wedge~b=a-2$.
  $\begin{array}{rclcl}
  A & = & a^2+a+1 & & \\
  & = & (b+2)^2+(b+2)+1 & & \\
  & = & b^2+4b+4+b+2+1 & & \\
  & = & b^2+5b+7 & \Longrightarrow & b=\pm1~\vee~b=\pm7\\
  B & = & 9b^2+b+1\\
  & = & 9(a-2)^2+(a-2)+1\\
  & = & 9a^2-36a+36+a-2+1\\
  & = & 9a^2-35a+35 & \Longrightarrow & a=\pm1~\vee~a=\pm5~\vee~a=\pm7~\vee~a=\pm35
  \end{array}$
  Here are only two possible solutions $(a,b)\in\left\{(1,-1),(-5,-7)\right\}$.
  But there are no solutions for this case because $\forall a,b:f(a)\ne g(b)$.
- ***Second case:*** $a-b=-2\Longrightarrow a=b-2~\wedge~b=a+2$.
  $\begin{array}{rclcl}
  A & = & a^2+a+1 & & \\
  & = & (b-2)^2+(b-2)+1 & & \\
  & = & b^2-4b+4+b-2+1 & & \\
  & = & b^2-3b+3 & \Longrightarrow & b=\pm1~\vee~b=\pm3\\
  B & = & 9b^2+b+1\\
  & = & 9(a+2)^2+(a+2)+1\\
  & = & 9a^2+36a+36+a+2+1\\
  & = & 9a^2+37a+39 & \Longrightarrow & a=\pm1~\vee~a=\pm3~\vee~a=\pm13~\vee~a=\pm39
  \end{array}$
  Here are only three possible solutions $(a,b)\in\left\{(-1,1),(1,3),(-3,-1)\right\}$.
  But there are no solutions for this case because $\forall a,b:f(a)\ne g(b)$.
- ***Third case:*** $a-b=4\Longrightarrow a=b+4~\wedge~b=a-4$.
  $\begin{array}{rclcl}
  A & = & a^2+a+1 & & \\
  & = & (b+4)^2+(b+4)+1 & & \\
  & = & b^2+8b+16+b+4+1 & & \\
  & = & b^2+9b+21 & \Longrightarrow & b=\pm1~\vee~b=\pm3~\vee~b=\pm7~\vee~b=\pm21\\
  B & = & 9b^2+b+1\\
  & = & 9(a-4)^2+(a-4)+1\\
  & = & 9a^2-72a+144+a-4+1\\
  & = & 9a^2-71a+141 & \Longrightarrow & a=\pm1~\vee~a=\pm3~\vee~a=\pm47~\vee~a=\pm141
  \end{array}$
  Here are only three possible solutions $(a,b)\in\left\{(1,-3),(3,-1),(-3,-7)\right\}$.
  But there are no solutions for this case because $\forall a,b:f(a)\ne g(b)$.
- ***Fourth case:*** $a-b=-4\Longrightarrow a=b-4~\wedge~b=a+4$.
  $\begin{array}{rclcl}
  A & = & a^2+a+1 & & \\
  & = & (b-4)^2+(b-4)+1 & & \\
  & = & b^2-8b+16+b-4+1 & & \\
  & = & b^2-7b+13 & \Longrightarrow & b=\pm1~\vee~b=\pm13\\
  B & = & 9b^2+b+1\\
  & = & 9(a+4)^2+(a+4)+1\\
  & = & 9a^2+72a+144+a+4+1\\
  & = & 9a^2+73a+149 & \Longrightarrow & a=\pm1~\vee~a=\pm141
  \end{array}$
  Here are no possible solutions $(a,b)\in\left\{\right\}$.
  But there are no solutions for this case because $\forall a,b:f(a)\ne g(b)$.

So ***it is proved***.

***PD:*** also I think $a=b=0$ is the unique (integer) solution for this equation, but I haven't proved this, what I proved is $a-b$ is a perfect cube and both $a$ and $b$ are even for all solutions to this equation.

Comment: How do you conclude that $gcd(X,b)=1$?

Answer (score 1):

Revised proof:

We have $(a-b)(a^2 + b^2 + ab + a + b + 1) = (2b)^3$

From OP, we see that if $p$ divides $d$ then $p$ divides $2b \implies p \mid 2$ or $p \mid b$.

Assume $p$ doesn't divide $2$.

$p \mid b \implies p \mid a$ but then $p$ does not divide $a^2+b^2+ab +a+b+1$.

Therefore $p=1$ or $p=2$. If $p=1$ then $a-b$ is a cube.

If $p=2$ then since $p$ does not divide $b$ both $a$ and $b$ are odd.

Now $a^2 + b^2 + ab + a + b + 1 \ne 0 \mod 4$. Therefore largest power
 of $2$ in $a^2 + b^2 + ab + a + b + 1$ is $2$.

Largest power of $2$ in $a-b$ should be $4$ (as $b$ is odd)

So one possibility is $a-b = 4m^3$ and $a^2 + b^2 + ab + a + b + 1 = 2n^3$ where $b = mn$

I guess I am stuck at this point.

Comment: If $a,b$ are odd, how do you get that $a-b=8$?

Comment: if $a,b$ are odd, then $d$ is a multiple of $2$. $a-b$ divides $8b^3$ and since $a-b$ and $b$ cannot have a common prime factor, $a-b = 8$.

Comment: Can't $a-b$ be $2$ or $4$?

Comment: @sku How do you prove that $a=b=0$ is the only solution.

Comment: I added a new proof.

Comment: Can you explain why we can say that "We get $d^2 xy = (2b)^3\implies d^2,x,y$ are all cubes."? How about the case where $\gcd(d,x)\not=1$, for example, $d=x=2,y=3^3$?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I rewrote the proof. Hope it is better now.

Comment: @Taha - do you follow the solution?

Comment: What is $y$ in your proof?

Comment: sorry, fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider the Diophantine equation
$$(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2+a+b+1) = 8b^3.\tag1$$
Let $\ \gcd(a,b) = d.$

$\text{If }\mathbf {d > 1,}\text{ then }a=md,\quad b=nd,\quad \gcd(m,n) = 1,$
$$(m-n)\left((m^2+mn+n^2)d^2 + (m+n)d + 1\right) = 8d^2n^3.\tag2$$
${\text{If }\mathbf{2\mid d},\ \text{then}}$ 
$$2\mid m-n,\quad 2\nmid (m^2+mn+n^2)d^2 + (m+n)d + 1,$$
$$d\mid m-n,\quad \gcd(d, m^2+mn+n^2)d^2 + (m+n)d + 1) = 1,$$
so
$$m-n=\pm8d^2,\quad (m^2+mn+n^2)d^2 + (m+n)d + 1 = \pm n^3,$$
$$a-b = \pm8d^3 = (\pm2d)^3.$$

$\text{If }\mathbf {(d > 2)\wedge (d\nmid2),}\text{ then the case } (2\nmid m+n)\text{ contradicts with (2), so }$
$$2\nmid m,\quad 2\nmid n,\quad (m-n=\pm 2d^2) \vee (m-n = \pm4d^2),$$
$$\left[\begin{align}
&\begin{cases}
m = n\pm2d^2\\
4d^6 - 3d^2n(n\pm2d^2) + 2d(n\pm d^2) + 1 = \pm4n^3
\end{cases}\\
&\begin{cases}
m = n\pm4d^2\\
16d^6 - 3d^2n(n\pm4d^2) + 2d(n\pm2d^3) + 1 = \pm2n^3,
\end{cases}
\end{align}\right.$$
$$\left[\begin{align}
&\begin{cases}
m = n\pm2d^2\\
\mp4n^3 - 3d^2n^2 + 2d(1\mp3d^3)n + 4d^6 \pm2d^3  + 1 = 0
\end{cases}\\
&\begin{cases}
m = n\pm4d^2\\
\mp2n^3 - 3d^2n^2 + 2d(1\mp6d^2)n + 16d^6 \pm4d^3 + 1 = 0,
\end{cases}
\end{align}\right.$$
and both of systems leads to the same equation without solutions
$$d^2n^2+1\equiv0\pmod4.$$

$\text{If }\mathbf {d = 1,}\text{ then the proof of the previous case is valid. Solutions also do not.}$

Thus, the issue equation has the integer solutions only in the case $\mathbf{2\nmid \gcd(a,b)},$
when $\mathbf{a-b}\ $ is a perfect cube.

Comment: How do you conclude that $m-n=8d^2$?

Comment: @TahaAkbari Fixed and improved, thanks.

Comment: In the case$m-n=\pm 2d^2$ I got $d^2n^2 \pmod 1 (mod 4)$ not what you've written.

Comment: But the case $m-n=2d^2$ doesn't lead to that.